# Selenium Webdriver- Which is the better way to get data from an external data file

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am just trying to login into a web application and filling out the input criteria(10 text fields) and clicking on submit.I am getting data from xml.

My doubt here is we can  get input data from excel,xml,json,etc..But which is better,efficient and lightweight.Please suggest

Comment: Start writing some code, SO is not for suggestions, all methods are efficient it depends on your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can use different approaches. For example:

- If you want representation of object (you have object structure), you may store information in XML/json, load data into Entity and pass data into page using this Entity.
- If you want just load data and don't want to use objects or your data unstructured (it can't be represented as object), you may use txt/csv/excel
- something else (depends on your situation)